# Curl generated cookie file is not working when I try to send it on the next curl call

Tags: curl

I access url with:

```
curl 'localhost:8013/api/auth/login' -d '{"login": "*", "password": "*", "auth_method": "local"}' -c .auth
```

when I want to use generated cookie:

```
curl -b .auth http://127.0.0.1:8013/api/test -v
```

it fails, and don't see any cookie in verbose mode

but, when I extract use key and value from the cookie file:

```
curl -b 'token=123456' http://127.0.0.1:8013/api/test -v
```

it is working ok and in output, I can see the line:

```
> Cookie: a=1
```

I have tried, different file locations, absolute path, follow redirection but nothing helped.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

in login request, I am using `localhost`, in subsequent I am using `127.0.0.1`